# Ruby - ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, numeric, method-missing

I have the following class overwrite:

```
class Numeric
  @@currencies = {:dollar => 1, :yen => 0.013, :euro => 1.292, :rupee => 0.019}
  def method_missing(method_id)
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '').to_sym
    if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
      self * @@currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def in(destination_currency)
    destination_curreny = destination_currency.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '').to_sym
    if @@currencies.has_key?(destination_currency)
      self / @@currencies[destination_currency]
    else
      super 
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever the argument for in is plural for example : `10.dollars.in(:yens)` I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` but `10.dollars.in(:yen)` yields no error. Any idea why?

Comment: This question is off-topic because they will only allow us to close typo/syntax related questions as such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your made a typo: `destination_curreny` is not the same as `destination_currency`. So when the currency is plural, your `@@currencies.has_key?` test fails because it is look at the original symbol (`destination_currency`) rather than the singularized symbol (`destination_curreny`). That will trigger a `method_missing` call with two arguments (`method_id` and `destination_currency`) through the `super` call but you've declared your `method_missing` to take one argument. That's why the error message that you neglected to fully quote is complaining about `method_missing` rather than `in`.

Fix your typo:

```
def in(destination_currency)
  destination_currency = destination_currency.to_s.gsub(/s$/, '').to_sym
  #...
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
def in(destination_currency)
```

In Ruby this means that your `in` method takes exactly one argument.  Passing more arguments causes an error.

If you want to let it have a variable number of arguments do something like this with the splat operator:

```
def in(*args)
```

Comment: I don't get it, how am I passing it multiple args?